# DC Composite chart to include dynamic charts

Tags: dc.js

```
var composite = dc.compositeChart("#test_composed");
var LineChart1 =  dc.lineChart(composite)
            .dimension(yearDim)
            .colors('yellow')
            .group(spendPerYear, "Top Line")
            .dashStyle([2,2])

var LineChart2 = dc.lineChart(composite)
            .dimension(yearDim)
            .colors('blue')
            .group(incomePerYear, "Bottom Line")
            .dashStyle([5,5])

var abc = [LineChart1, LineChart2];

composite
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([2011,2013]))
    .yAxisLabel("The Y Axis")
    .legend(dc.legend().x(80).y(20).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .compose([
      //abc
    LineChart1, LineChart2
        ])
dc.renderAll();
```

So this code works. But in `.compose` how can I include `abc` array so that if I push more charts in `abc` array `.compose` will automatically update. I won't need to put each charts manually.

Essentially I want compose function like this

```
var abc = [LineChart1, LineChart2, LineChart3, LineChart4 ....];
composite
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([2011,2013]))
    .yAxisLabel("The Y Axis")
    .legend(dc.legend().x(80).y(20).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .compose([
      abc
    ])
```

Comment: Hi, please use the dc.js tag for questions about the charting library - dc is quite something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `.compose` as a `multi-dimensional` array. use following code instead:

```
var abc = [LineChart1, LineChart2, LineChart3, LineChart4 ....];
composite
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([2011,2013]))
    .yAxisLabel("The Y Axis")
    .legend(dc.legend().x(80).y(20).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .compose(abc)
```